# jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js issue on website

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube

I can't figure why the youtube video has stopped working suddenly, the video URL is working fine, I am not able to find any issue with the HTML code, not sure what is wrong, can anyone please check the [website](http://goo.gl/R2HO2M) and let me know what the real problem is, thanks.

I am getting this in Console "TypeError: this.match(...) is null"

```js
String.prototype.getVideoID = function () { var movieURL; if (this.substr(0, 16) == "youtu.be/") { movieURL = this.replace("youtu.be/";, ""); } else if (this.indexOf("http") > -1) { movieURL = this.match(/[\\?&]v=([^&#]*)/)[1]; } else { movieURL = this } return movieURL; }; var isDevice = 'ontouchstart' in window; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { if (jQuery.mbYTPlayer.YTAPIReady) return; jQuery(document).trigger("YTAPIReady"); jQuery.mbYTPlayer.YTAPIReady = true; } –
```

Comment: Can you include some of your code, please? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Read this please — http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.